# Prevent ScrollViewer scrolling

Tags: wpf, scroll, treeview

How can I prevent a WPF (3.5) TreeView scroll event?

There is a `ScrollViewer_ScrollChanged` event, but that is not good, as that is called **after** the scroll happened, so I can only undo the scroll, not prevent.
I am looking something like this (pseudo):

```
ScrollViewer_ScrollChangING(EventParam e)
{
    if (...)
       e.Cancel = true;
}
```

Thanks

**EDIT**

I want to have scrollbars, and user should be able to scroll, **except** when some condition happens `if (...)` - only **then** prevent scroll dynamically.

More precisely, I want the scrollbars to have **only** integer position, so if user scrolls to 1000.45, it should be adjusted to 1000.
This is because otherwise WPF has rendering problems with bitmap in the tree...
If we allow scroll position to be integer only, then rendering seems ok.
(no, SnapToDevicePixels does not help, and no, we cannot use LayouRouding)

Comment: which control you are using?

Comment: Actually it's a Grid, which contains 3 columns. In the first, is a TreeView. That's what being scrolled. However, I don't know if the scrollbar belongs the the Tree or to the Grid. But should not really matter, it's a ScrollViewer at the end.

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to this?

Comment: @Vultuxe - to be honest, I don't remember, it was long time ago

Answer (score 0):

The workaround can look like this:

```
private void TreeView_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.OriginalSource is System.Windows.Controls.Border)
    {
    ...your code
    }
}
private void TreeView_PreviewMouseWheel(object sender, MouseWheelEventArgs e)
{
...your code
}
```

Comment: No, I want to have a scrollbar, and want the user to be able to use it. Except, let's say, when user tries to scroll over position 1000, then do not allow that. Or whatever condition, see my pseudo example in the question. `if (...)`

Comment: From this, how will I know that what is the VerticalChange / HorizontalChange during the scroll? I did not try, but your suggestion will only say that somebody clicked on the Scrollbar, isn't it? Not the details.

Comment: Updated the question again, to see why I want this, maybe other solution also exists